# iOS8 add image to push notification

Tags: image, ios8, push-notification, lockscreen

Is there a way to add a small bitmap image in a push notification for display? The image does not have to be remotely downloaded, it can be accessed from my app bundle if that's even possible. This question has been asked before but for older os versions. Now the notification payload has increased to 2KB.

Is it possible to show an image in a push notification?

If so, is it possible to have an image show in a notification on the lockscreen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image shown in the push notification on the lockscreen is the app icon. This *cannot* be customized.

However, the text that is show next to this can. That includes all supported unicode characters, so you can add emoji icons. Check [emojipedia](http://emojipedia.org/apple-emoji-list/) for a full list of available icons.

Comment: Yup, you can only add unicode characters. You cannot add a bitmap image of your own as part of the text.